# System.ArgumentNullException: 'value can't be null Parametre name: source'

Tags: c#, exception

I have a program which connects to a site and gets the list of orders using soap api. But i have a really strange issue. When a i try to get the orders of a day which there is no orders and then try get list of orders of a day i get this error. But strange thing is if a put a break point to line where i got the error and evalute the program step by step i don't get any errors. How could that happen. herre is the code.

```
https://api.n11.com/ws/OrderService.wsdl

using n11.Deneme.Forms.com.n11.api;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace n11.Deneme.Forms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strStartDate = "18/01/2020";
            string strEndDate = "18/01/2020";

            long totalCountValue = 50;
            int currentPageValue = 0;
            int pageCountValue = 1;
            int pageSizeValue = 50;

            Authentication auth = new Authentication();
            auth.appKey = "b891a6b9-cb97-4a7e-9ffb-f7b1e2a593e8";
            auth.appSecret = "pHCjYYadxwTG64Ej";

            OrderSearchPeriod orderSearchPeriod = new OrderSearchPeriod();
            orderSearchPeriod.startDate = strStartDate;
            orderSearchPeriod.endDate = strEndDate;

            OrderDataListRequest orderDataListRequest = new OrderDataListRequest();
            //orderDataListRequest.status = "1";
            orderDataListRequest.period = orderSearchPeriod;
            //orderDataListRequest.orderNumber = "209524598478";

            PagingData pagingData = new PagingData();
            pagingData.currentPage = currentPageValue;
            pagingData.pageCount = pageCountValue;
            pagingData.pageSize = pageSizeValue;
            pagingData.totalCount = totalCountValue;

            DetailedOrderListRequest request = new DetailedOrderListRequest();
            request.auth = auth;
            request.pagingData = pagingData;
            request.searchData = orderDataListRequest;

            OrderServicePortService port = new OrderServicePortService();
            DetailedOrderListResponse response = port.DetailedOrderList(request);
            List<DetailedOrderData> orderList = response.orderList.ToList();

            foreach (var order in orderList)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(order.totalAmount.ToString() + " - " + order.orderNumber + " - " + order.citizenshipId + " - " + order.createDate);

                long orderIdValue = order.id;

                OrderDataRequest orderDataRequest = new OrderDataRequest();
                orderDataRequest.id = orderIdValue;

                OrderDetailRequest orderdetailrequest = new OrderDetailRequest();
                orderdetailrequest.auth = auth;
                orderdetailrequest.orderRequest = orderDataRequest;


                OrderServicePortService port1 = new OrderServicePortService();
                OrderDetailResponse orderDetailResponse = port1.OrderDetail(orderdetailrequest);
                OrderDetailData orderDetail = orderDetailResponse.orderDetail;

                MessageBox.Show(orderDetail.orderNumber);

                List<OrderSearchData> orderItemList = orderDetail.itemList.ToList();

                foreach (var item in orderItemList)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(item.shipmentInfo.campaignNumber);

                }


            }

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: You may wanna regenerate your API secrets, since you published them in the post.

Comment: i know thanks a lot

Comment: u can't really do anything with that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the error on the line:

```cs
List<DetailedOrderData> orderList = response.orderList.ToList();   //I GOT THE ERROR ON THIS LINE
```

then the thing to do is to look at how `response.orderList` gets a value. In particular, does it do something with threads, tasks, timers, external events, or anything else like that - which could mean that it gets populated *shortly after* the initial return from `DetailedOrderList`, which could explain why it works when you debug and step through (adding a crucial delay into things).

You could also simply do:

```cs
var tmp = response.orderList;
if (tmp == null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
    "hey, response.orderList was null! this is not good!");
List<DetailedOrderData> orderList = tmp.ToList();
return orderList;
```

which would make it very clear and explicit that this is what is happening. If you *don't* get this exception, but something else, then: more debugging needed!

Comment: now i get this exception so do i need to put a delay is that what you mean?

Comment: @devrimderi no, now you need to find out why it is `null` initially; I can't tell you what is happening there : only you have the code for `DetailedOrderList`; adding an arbitrary delay is a *terrible* hack that just kicks the can down the road - it doesn't address the actual issue

Comment: i can't understand what is happening cause when i trace it doen't occur. So if i evaluta step by step i got ZERO count of orders but if i don't i get null so really don't know what to do

Comment: @devrimderi you need to *look at how/when `.orderList` gets assigned a value*; and work backwards from there - how does *that* code get called - and so on. There is nothing I can do to help you with that since I can't see the code for any of those pieces.

Comment: first startdate = 18.01.2020 enddate = 18.01.2020 then after i call change the dates to 17.01.2020 u can only get this error by doing these

Answer (score 0):

```
if(response.orderList == null)
            {
                var temp = button1_Click.PerformClick();
                return temp;           
            }
            else
            {
                List<DetailedOrderData> orderList = response.orderList.ToList();

                return orderList;
            }
```

Comment: i solved the issue ike this but i don't really like to use it this way anyone got ideas?